# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, caused by NullPointerException?

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, scene

This is my first time attempting a project using JavaFX and i'm having some trouble with an exception that i don't quite understand. I'm getting this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sun.glass.ui.Timer.resume()" because "this.pulseTimer" is null
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.resumeTimer(QuantumToolkit.java:542)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$PulseTask.set(QuantumToolkit.java:213)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.requestNextPulse(QuantumToolkit.java:906)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.markDirtyLayout(Parent.java:940)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.requestLayout(Parent.java:964)
    at javafx.scene.layout.StackPane.requestLayout(StackPane.java:322)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$8.invalidated(Scene.java:1247)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.setRoot(Scene.java:1196)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:360)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:211)
    at Presentation.DisplayTest.<clinit>(DisplayTest.java:11)
```

When i attempt to run this code:

```
package Presentation;

import Domain.Domain;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DisplayTest {
    static StackPane root = new StackPane();
    static Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    static Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Velkommen til (Spil navn)!");
        Domain.initEverything();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Klima Kurv");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        InventoryManagerGFX.initInventoryManagerGFX(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println("Spillet er færdigt!");
    }

    public static void gameOnGoing() {
        while (!Domain.GetIsDone()) {
            System.out.print("> ");
            String line = Domain.GetNextLine();
            Domain.dispatch(line);
        }
    }
}
```

The error message does not appear if i delete the static initialisations at the beginning. Does anyone here know what to do?

Also, english is not my first language so sorry if i have made any grammatical errors.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are 2 different languages, I would remove the JavaScript tag here.

Answer (score 4):

You are not using JavaFX correctly. There are at least two problems with your code:

1. You are creating UI (user interface) objects before the JavaFX platform has been started (the cause, I believe, of the `NullPointerException` in this case).
2. You are constructing and modifying a `Stage` on a thread other than the *JavaFX Application Thread*, which is not allowed.

I recommend researching more about JavaFX before trying to write an application with it. For example, you can read the [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) guide to see how to set up a basic JavaFX application (with any of the major Java IDEs and/or build tools, whether your own code is modular or not). And the Javadoc of [`javafx.application.Application`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) will explain the lifecycle of JavaFX. There are also quite a few tutorials out there on the internet, books you can buy, and other Stack Overflow Q&As regarding JavaFX which will help you learn more about JavaFX.

There are a few ways to start the JavaFX platform. However, a typical JavaFX application will do it by having its main class extend `Application`. So, your class should potentially look more like this:

```java
package Presentation;

import Domain.Domain;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DisplayTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(DisplayTest.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        System.out.println("Velkommen til (Spil navn)!");
        Domain.initEverything();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Klima Kurv");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        InventoryManagerGFX.initInventoryManagerGFX(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println("Spillet er færdigt!");
    }

    public static void gameOnGoing() {
        while (!Domain.GetIsDone()) {
            System.out.print("> ");
            String line = Domain.GetNextLine();
            Domain.dispatch(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Though I cannot promise that fixes all your problems, as I have no idea how your `Domain` and `InventoryMangagerGFX` classes are implemented. Also, note that in this case, the `main` method is not actually necessary (if you have `DisplayTest` as the main class and JavaFX is on the module-path).

On a related note, you might want to reconsider a few things about your application:

1. Overuse of static state is a sign of bad design. Java is [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), so you should make use of objects; follow [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID); use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (which is just a fancy way of saying pass objects via constructors and/or methods); and so on. Additionally, consider using a proper application architecture like [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC), [Model-View-Presenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) (MVP), [Model-View-ViewModel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) (MVVM), or another.
2. It is strange to use `System.in`, presumably as part of the `GetNextLine()` implementation, in a GUI (Graphical User Interface) application. Reading from the standard input stream is something done in CLI (Command Line Interface) applications. Create *either* a GUI application or a CLI application, not a mix of both. Note that GUI applications are inherently [event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming), so having that `while (!Domain.GetIsDone())` loop does not make much sense.
3. Follow [standard Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). Or, at the very least, you should be consistent.